# Adding Native UI component to React Native does nothing

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to add material design input to React Native, but unfortunately it renders nothing and I can't find what am I missing.

This is my module. I pass two params and return TextInputLayout.

```
public class MaterialTextInputModule extends SimpleViewManager<TextInputLayout> {
@Nonnull
@Override
public String getName() {
    return "MaterialTextInput";
}

@Nonnull
@Override
protected TextInputLayout createViewInstance(@Nonnull ThemedReactContext reactContext) {
    TextInputLayout textInputLayout = new TextInputLayout(reactContext, null, R.style.Widget_MaterialComponents_TextInputLayout_OutlinedBox);
    TextInputEditText textInput = new TextInputEditText(textInputLayout.getContext());
    textInputLayout.addView(textInput);
    return textInputLayout;
}

@ReactProp(name="hint")
public void setHint(TextInputLayout textInputLayout, @Nullable String hint) {
    textInputLayout.setHint(hint);
}

@ReactProp(name="outlined")
public void setOutlinedBox(TextInputLayout textInputLayout, Boolean outlined) {
    if (outlined) {
        textInputLayout.setBoxBackgroundMode(TextInputLayout.BOX_BACKGROUND_OUTLINE);
    }
}}
```

This is my package class, where I create view managers:

```
public class MaterialTextInputPackage implements ReactPackage {
@Nonnull
@Override
public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(@Nonnull ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    return Collections.emptyList();
}

@Override
public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    return Arrays.<ViewManager>asList(
        new MaterialTextInputModule()
    );
}}
```

I also add this as a package in MainApplication and then required native component in rn app. Then I just use it like this

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import MaterialTextInput from './MaterialTextInput';

const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' + 'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
  android:
    'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
    'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MaterialTextInput hint={"Hello my first component"} outlined={true}></MaterialTextInput>
      </View>
    );
  }}
```

This is how I require a component, basically it's MaterialTextInput.js

```
import {requireNativeComponent} from 'react-native';


module.exports = requireNativeComponent('MaterialTextInput', TextInput);
```

Comment: Never wrote my own native module, but you don't import it directly. First you import `NativeModules` from react-native. Then you do something like this `const { MaterialTextInput } = NativeModules`

Comment: @Ziyo unfortunately, it doesn't solve problem. I'm importing an UI component, so you should use a requireNativeComponent and I'm already using it.

Comment: @Ziyo found an answer, if you are interested

Comment: awesome. I learned something new 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I found an answer and what a silly mistake it was. Basically there was no problem in native code, but just a small error in JSX. After refactoring files I just added style to ui component which I just added. Works amazing :)

Anyway, working code in RN:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, requireNativeComponent } from 'react-native';

const MaterialTextInput = requireNativeComponent("MaterialTextInput")

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.top} />
        <MaterialTextInput style={styles.bottom} outlined={true} hint={'Hello my first component'} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  top: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  bottom: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});
```